# Use Robotium to test android project with library

Tags: android, robotium

I have an android application consisting of a library project that contains the source code.  I then have two additional projects, that are used to manage a pro, and lite version of the app.

I have been unable to get robotium to load the class files from either of my proxy apps(pro and lite, which reference the library via a module reference), or the library itself.  I have tried a bunch of different class names, and references, but the test project fails below.

```
public MainTest() {
    super("com.joe.app.lib", Main.class);
}
```

I haven't found any discussion here about testing with library projects in android.  Looking for advice.

Error msg

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.joe.app.tests/com.job.app.tests.MainTest}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.joe.tests.MainTest in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.joe.app.tests-1.apk]

Answer (score 1):

While not specific to Robotium, this [post](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-testing-external-libraries.html) may help you using external libraries in your test project.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found a solution yet or others are getting to this question due to similar errors after the last the adt update.

In `Project Properties` of your Test Project go to item `Java Build Path` and select tab `Order and Export`. There you'll have to check the project you're testing against so it's properly exported.

For latest ADT you also have to have the `Android Private Libraries` exported in your projects.